# Tried to add a self-answered wiki-post, but just got downvotes

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes, self-answer, community-wiki

I've tried to contribute to the community by publishing a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253981/recursive-solution-to-check-if-string-is-a-palindrome-java?noredirect=1#comment35583585_23253981) to a problem.

I thought it is allowed and welcome on SE. But then I get many downvotes and that's it. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Ask yourself this - separately is that a good question or a good answer? If one is not objectively good by the standards of the site that's why you've got downvotes. The ability to answer your own question doesn't enable you to abrogate your other responsibilities.

Comment: There's a lot of related questions on Meta.SE, because people tend to react strongly to self-answered Q's. See [What can be done to improve moderation of self answered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137353), [How to correctly post a qa style question, i.e. self answer without it failing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186983), ["Answer your own question -- share your knowledge" gets downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155193)

Comment: I appreciate your effort in the question.  It's just unfortunate that, taken by itself, the question is classic "help vampire"/"give me teh codez", which is ironic because you are attempting the opposite :/  I'm not sure there is any way other than inventing a fake bug in your code, and even that would probably attract downvotes...

Comment: @Will maybe create a "self-answer" tag? Still though, not sure how useful a "recursive solution to check if a string is a palindrome" is, unless you're trying to cheat on a homework question or an employment screen `:/`

Comment: @DenisKulagin keep in mind that if you edit the question to improve it, you can perhaps convince people to undelete it...but like I said, not sure how useful that solution really is, since it's basically a made-up problem that you're highly unlikely to encounter as ***an actual problem*** that needs to be solved in real life `:/` See [On Interviewing Programmers](http://blog.codinghorror.com/on-interviewing-programmers/): "I just can't muster any enthusiasm for completely random arbitrary problems in the face of so many *actual* problems." -- Jeff Atwood.

Comment: Ok. Problem is made up. But where the edge between actual and made up problems? Should anyone ever post an implementation of Binary Search Tree on the Internet? Because anyone, who passed DS&A course could easily write an implementation of BST in their favourite PL. Actually this could be said of any other problem. AVL tree? Not a problem, just read Thomas H. Cormen and write it yourself)

Comment: In my opinion, the problem is that self-answered questions are not marked anyhow different from those which require an answer. Of course when people see a question without even an attempt to produce a solution, they start downvoting.

Comment: @DenisKulagin data structures actually have a wide variety of practical applications. Checking if a string is a palindrome? Not so much `:/`. From [help/on-topic]: questions must generally cover "practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development". In my opinion, the question fails the **practical** criterion. But that's just my take on it, maybe other people will disagree.

Comment: @DenisKulagin I had a similar issue here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305794/how-to-deal-with-downvotes-on-self-answered-questions?noredirect=1#comment245689_305794 Why not just delete the whole of StackOverflow and open source, just because *it is possible* that anyone will re-iterate the path of informatics over a century ;-) ? I say that, regardless of whether *any specific user will find it useful*, such questions need to stay.

Comment: @Cupcake I totally disagree. I have worked with binary sequences in data processing some time ago. Go figure, it is actually sometimes useful to check binary sequences for palindrome-ish properties. Under some circumstances I might have actually used the algorithm from the OP. Sorry, but only because *you* don't find it useful does not mean *at all* that there is no-one that *could* find it useful. So why on earth would you delete possibly valuable information?

Comment: @UliKöhler look, at the end of the day, regardless of whether or not the problem of checking if a string is a palindrome has useful real-world applications (which you point out that it does), *the question simply does not meet community standards for a well-asked question*. In this case, as just one issue to be pointed out, it fails the standard of demonstrating that the asker has attempted to solve the problem, and given a code sample in the question body (for example) to demonstrate where exactly the asker is stuck.

Comment: @Cupcake Sorry, but that's not an actual argument. You say that useful infomation should be deleted because the answer has not been copied in the question? I seriously have issues with this attitude. SO is there to help people. People can not be helped when information is removed for this reason. I'd say it's OK if closing & deleting would mean only the question would be removed. But the answer will be removed with it after all.

Comment: @UliKöhler please read [these questions and their answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251874/tried-to-add-a-self-answered-wiki-post-but-just-got-downvotes?noredirect=1#comment5186_251874) mentioned by Josh. Especially the question and answers to [What can be done to improve moderation of self-answered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137353/163250).

Comment: @UliKöhler Stack Overflow is not the only programming site on the internet. Removing information here does not mean it's gone from the collective knowledge of humanity forever. There are plenty of other places where someone could share such knowledge, such as in programming forums, or a blog post.

Comment: @Cupcake While that is often true that does not mean I can appreciate removing it somewhere because it might be somewhere else... indeed I have read a lot of things on SO that I have not found elsewhere (one of the reasons why SO is great!)

Comment: @UliKöhler it's worth pointing out that the question [Check string for palindrome](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4138827/456814) already exists on Stack Overflow. There's little to no reason why the OP's solution couldn't have been posted to that question instead. Though keep in mind that even that question may not quite meet community standards either, as it is rather broad and open-ended: "*I tested it and it seems to work. However I want to know if it is right or if there is something to improve.*"

Comment: @Cupcake OK, I must have missed that. In that case, of course, you are right and it should probably be posted there. I don't think that downvotes would be inherently wrong on such a question but I believe it is always a bad thing if the answers to such a question (provided there are any and they might be useful to someone) get deleted just because the question is deleted. Besides that, no objections!

Comment: @UliKöhler again, my original point still holds true. There's no reason why these solutions ***must*** exist on Stack Overflow. If anyone feels that strongly that they must be shared, they can write a blog post about them. People can (and should) use Google to find them. SO does not need to be the one and only one source of all programming knowledge in the world, nor is it meant to be, nor should it be.

Answer (score 86):

Questions asked on this site are expected to be of high quality.  The fact that you answered it yourself is entirely irrelevant; questions will be evaluated in isolation. The question should be a good question even if you don't answer it yourself.  A two sentence rough description of a project to be solved is a *terrible* question.  What would you do if you saw someone post a question like that?  Hopefully you'd downvote it, as was done here.

The answer is not particularly great either.  It's just a code dump.  There are no explanations or details.

Comment: +1 the stack in hierarchy of acceptable things, things we keep and adore begins with good questions

Comment: Yeah, just code isn't a very good answer, I might have been inclined to downvote too. Definitely would've needed an explanation, especially the overall algorithm, which could even be language-agnostic.

Comment: Oh, by the way, another problem with self-answered questions where the questions are of poor quality is that it sets a bad example for other people (who don't already have answers) to ***actually*** ask poor questions `:P`

Comment: One man's trash is another man's treasure.

Answer (score 21):

You can certainly self answer your own question. [In fact you are encouraged to do so](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). However, the question and the answer must still adhere to the standards here. Meaning the question must be complete and thorough, describing the issue you are having and what you've attempted to overcome it. And the answer must be complete explaining the solution along with providing relevant code or links to docs.

For that reason, self answering questions are much harder than a normal question because you already have the answer to it so wording a question is tricky. In general, most self answered questions on SO don't fare well for this very reason.

As @me how points out in the comments there is [even a badge for doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner). So if you are looking for some examples of people that have done it right that would be a great place to start.

Comment: I have seen these Q/As self-answered and they are worth the time to read (if you work with those technologies, of course): stackoverflow.com/q/2793150/1065197 stackoverflow.com/q/11988415/1065197 stackoverflow.com/q/247621/1065197. The problems I found in OP's Q/A are mainly described here: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811/182862).

Comment: +1 if fact you can [get a badge for it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) if it gets 3 upvotes ;)

Comment: I would add that if you are answering your own question this quality threshold is *even greater* (because people, rightly or wrongly, can see it as playing the system)

Comment: About encouragement to answering your own questions QA style (as opposed to finding answer after asking and then answering because nobody else gave the same answer). There certainly is text saying so, but community by and large does not like it. So I think the encouraging text should perhaps be removed or clarified ("If you do this, Q&A better be of stellar quality"), since it sends a mixed signal and leads to frustration: poster thought he was doing a good thing, but gets punished by downvotes.

Comment: @hyde I still feel that the community's negative reaction to self answered questions still tends to be more because of the quality and less because the person answered their own question. It's just such a difficult thing to do correctly.

Comment: @MatthewGreen I don't really disagree, I just think it'd be fair if "newbies" were not encouraged to do that (by showing them the *"Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style"* checkbox), or at least were warned about the likely result.

Comment: @hyde Alt descriptive text for "answer your own question": "How are your acting skills? Did you very precisely simulate the mind of an asker who has recently struggled for days to find the thing that you already know how to do, even if you learned it years ago? Does your popularity magic 8 ball make you think that this question will have somewhat broad appeal? Are you really sure you don't want to start a blog or submit pull requests to the official docs? If you answered yes to all three, go ahead and click Submit."

Answer (score 12):

I'd hazard a guess at:

1. You didn't form it as a question
2. There's not a specific thing you're trying to get an answer to (you're solving a programming task rather than trying to gain a specific piece of information)
3. It duplicates material [already on the site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816878/palindrome-coding)

Answer (score 11):

I realize I may be putting a small chunk of *hard earned* reputation at risk by exposing this as an example but I have just recently [asked and answered my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23129359/how-to-put-an-ampersand-in-a-header-footer-in-excel).

I randomly ran into a problem putting an ampersand in a header in Excel. I searched Stack Overflow, and Google. I have found an answer on an off-site resource but since I couldn't find a matching question/answer like that on SO I decided to post a question and answer it myself so any future people who run into the same problem can easily find a reference to a solution.

Note: I really have tried to follow guidelines for asking a good question - simply, not to get the question closed within the first 10 views. I tried to at least describe what I was doing and what the problem was. I though I made it clear what the problem was...

Posted an answer to it within minutes... As it turned out in the end I have got two votes on my question; a downvote and an upvote and (*surprisingly*) 3 uvotes on the answer.

I have used my own as an example so hopefully no-other SO member will experience a random waterfall of up/downvotes.

What my advice is for you in the future:

- Research Stack Overflow, make sure the question you are about to ask and answer yourself has not been asked before.
- Form your question according to [how-to-ask guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) just try to make sure it's not a sentence long question/answer.
- Any content that remains on SO is considered useful and helpful to future visitors, make sure you make it a useful resource for any future reader. Explain your specific problem in a question and explain well why your answer is the best

Just to add on top of this all - I have previously asked questions which I happened to answer some time later - I have had no intention of answering while posting to it's perfectly fine to do that. You even get a [badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) if your answer to own question receives 3 votes :)

Answer (score 6):

It seems you wrote a long-winded (code-wise) and stylistically suboptimal solution without explaining your approach.  You might want to post your code on codereview.stackexchange.com to get feedback about the style, or look at the comments on SO.

Your question in particular needed to show work.  Now that you've shown it, you're allowed to post it as an answer and check that you were able to answer it yourself.