# Can a self-answer be not-an-answer?

Tags: discussion, self-answer, not-an-answer

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308770/prevent-floating-div-from-wrapping-when-resized), which was self-answered with an answer consisting solely of

> Solved: http://jsbin.com/usake4/9/

with no explanation.  This question has (pre-meta effect) 959 views, including one user who commented on the answer to ask for an explanation.

I think this answer counts as "not an answer", as it cannot stand on its own without the link (and the link doesn't seem to explain itself either, though I'm not a jquery expert).

On one hand, it's good that the user indicated they no longer need an answer; on the other hand, this answer provides no explanation, making it very unuseful for other readers, and having the question marked as answered discourages other users from providing a useful answer.

Should such not-an-answer self-answers be flagged as usual?

Comment: Just flag it, no matter if the OP answered.

Comment: Would've been great if you'd answered this question.

Comment: Now the answer is gone and random visitors (one of another 959) won't find their question answered. Is that better?

Comment: this is the epitome of *"too localized"* nobody would be harmed if the entire question was deleted!

Comment: No.  Criticize with comments, but **DO NOT FLAG IT**.  Even if it is a bad answer, it conveys important information that the poster considers their problem resolved.  Flags often lead to deletion with little further thought, and having the poster's view of the question deleted from the eyes of all but high rep users makes the question falsely appear to still be unresolved.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: From the point of view of any other user, though, the question *is* unresolved (or so badly resolved it does not matter); therefore, either the question is worthy and should be addressed (improve existing answer or post a better one) or it is not worthy and should be culled.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Unquestionably that is not an answer; just being a self-answer doesn't change the guidelines for voting/flagging/etc.

Flag as "Not an answer" and downvote. A comment indicating *why* this isn't an answer is always nice. Chances are the user just doesn't understand what that feature is there for (happens a lot).

Comment: No.  Criticize it all you want, but removing an answer **from the poster themselves**, *even* if it is a *bad* one, does a **serious dis-service to everyone** but making the question look unresolved.  Remember only high-rep users can see deleted answers.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Actually it seems like moderators agree with removing that content. The answer didn't provide enough information ot be useful to anyone other than the OP himself, and as such the question **is** unresolved for all other readers and should be marked as such.

Comment: No, the question is resolved - and often the poster will never return.  Such **vandalized-by-the-community** questions remain derelict, clogging up the site to the detriment of all.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251874/tried-to-add-a-self-answered-wiki-post-but-just-got-downvotes?rq=1 It doesn't mention flagging, but does indicate that the community doesn't give quality exceptions for self-answered content. Given that questions are more for future visitors than the OP; I would say clean-up seems reasonable. If you still disagree, I would post a dissenting answer and see what people think.

Comment: This is indeed, an example of how "the community" often **vandalizes** the site.  Take a step back, come here with fresh ideas instead of pre-conceived assumptions (remember also to view without logging in) and the resulting damage will be obvious.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Just to play one last devils advocate here; what happens when that link goes dead? Now the problem is actually **worse** because it *looks* like the problem is solved, but the solution is inaccessible. In fact, this is why link-only answers are supposed to be deleted.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the link is live or dead, it still says "hey, I consider my problem solved" with an implicit "you may not want to waste your time on this question, because I probably don't care about it any more".  **That is key information which often gets censored when thoughtless flagging leads to equally thoughtless deletion**.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I think we'll have to agree to disagree. I really do think you should post a dissenting answer; its Meta, the points don't count :). For me, I'd rather see someone go "Hey, this post doesn't have an answer, I'll answer it!" and add useful information to the site rather than ignore it and leave a dead link in place so that a future visitor has no chance of getting the information. Yes, thats not a good strategy for getting reputation, but I believe it leaves the site in a better place, regardless of whether the OP ever sees it. Post an answer (or question) though!

Comment: The fundamental problem is that, while people understandably **want to object to the low quality of the answer**, the *impact* of objection-by-flagging is **destructive to the site in general**.  Folks need to grow up and start thinking if the *outcome* of their actions is going to be productive, or counterproductive by *hiding information* which will prevent others from *wasting their time* on dead ends.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It sounds like you would also have a problem with deleting an accepted answer of any sort, even if it was link-only by a different user. Again, this is more of a fundamental disagreement about what is good for the site. I would read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer and post a different Meta post, or a dissenting answer here, if you want to discuss it further.

Comment: "It sounds like you would also have a problem with deleting an accepted answer of any sort, even if it was link-only by a different user." indeed, in many cases I would and have.  **Ultimately, we need a way to register objection to the quality of content which does not destructively hide potentially important information from low-rep visitors**.  The linkage of "it's poor quality" to "it has to go" is fundamentally **illogical and destructive**.

Comment: @ChrisStratton cleaning out garbage is not destructive to the site.

Comment: Status information is not garbage.  That's the point you are missing - even if the "answer" itself were incomprehensible, the simple fact that one had been posted *by the asker themselves* would be a **critical piece of question status** that is is counterproductive to censor - such removal is indeed harmful to the site.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I completely see where you're coming from and understand what you're getting at. At the same time, there are rules for how content should be on this site. Yes, a self-answer from the OP "solves" the question, but at the same time, six months down the road another user can still post an answer to the question. Why? Not to help the OP, who has fixed their issue, but to help _other people who find the question and have that problem_. That's what this is about- Helping _future users_, not just the OP. (cont.)

Comment: By deleting answers that will be no use to other people who come across that answer, we make the _knowledge repository_ we are trying to build that much better and cleaner. While, yes, it does remove the indication that the OP has solved their problem, that's only part of the goal. The point is to have a solution to the problem available for other people who have said problem. So, if the link goes dead on a link only answer, who does it help? No one, so it should be deleted to make room for answers that will be helpful.

Comment: Maybe compromise by deleting the answer and editing it into the question to show that it was resolved?

Comment: @connor - that's better than nothing, but it still means the question would show with zero answers.  For the question in question, someone has laboriously copied the link target into an answer - which is great, but nowhere near the solution of busybodies refraining from dredging up 3-year-old questions to damage.

Comment: @connor It'd be edited right back out. Answers go in the answer section. Someone did post an answer as CW with the code from the link, and the link itself, with an explanation that it is the OP's own proposed solution that was deleted.

Comment: Couldn't the just have edited the original answer to include the code? I have to agree with chris here. I often find it useful to see what worked for the OP when I have the same issue even if it isn't the best answer

Comment: @Kendra is it an answer or not then? If it's considered an answer and edited out of a post then it should be considered an answer when flagging

Comment: @connor Yes, but in this case it was deleted by a moderator. The CW answer indicates it came from the OP's "answer" so thats pretty good in this case. The only problem is that it isn't "accepted"; which we'll just have to live with.

Comment: @connor I think that would've been the easier way to handle this situation, but that's a matter of opinion. Some people will edit a link-only answer to include the code/relevant information, some will just flag and go. Both are, by the standards of SO, proper ways to handle the situation.

Comment: @connor The original post **was not an answer**. The CW post (with the code included) **is** an answer (albeit a relatively poor one, it has no explanation).

Comment: If the OP has a solution that isn't worth of an answer, they should at least be able to mention it in their post.

Comment: If instead of posting on meta, this post was flagged for attention and the answer was deleted, the information is gone. If I had the same problem I'd find a question with one unaccepted answer. A deleted answer is just as useless as a dead link to over 99% of SO's users

Comment: @connor Without question; the *nice* thing to do, perhaps even the "right" thing to do would be to take the link and plug the content in. I will not argue that deleting is better than that. *With that said*, flagging is also a "correct" thing to do by SO community standards, and performing that edit is quite a bit of work, especially when its a blog post, not a fiddle (as it was here). In theory, the OP would perform the correct edit after deletion and flag for undeletion. Obviously it doesn't work that way, but I'm not going to say those that simply flagged were **wrong** here.

Comment: @connor If the OP has a solution, and would like to share, one would hope that they would give back to the community by posting a **proper** answer, instead of a crap one. **It doesn't matter if the problem is solved**; if its not on the site, its worth someone's time to post the answer to here.

Comment: @connor It'd be just as useless if the OP posted their "solved" link in the question and no one reading through the problem description to see if their problem was the same noticed that little tiny line at the bottom. I've done that several times to find answers by other users that worked. It does happen that a user finds their problem on SO, but it has no answer, and there are ways to deal with that.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I'd argue that the if the goal of the flag was to improve the site then they should edit instead of flagging. The letter of the law does say that all link only answers should be deleted, but in cases like this it diminishes the value of the site

Comment: @Kendra it may not help everyone. But I'm sure most people attempting to answer the question would notice it. Again, I think that the answer shouldn't be deleted in the first place, but if that's not an option, then it isn't fair to say the OP can't mention how they solved their problem in the question

Comment: @connor You're overlooking the part where Bradley and I agreed that the answer should have been edited, that would have been better. But it wasn't the only right way to handle the answer. It _is_ an option. It's the option that was not chosen this time, and that's a shame. Since it _is_ an option, the rule does still make sense and is fair.

Comment: Very long discussion. The deletion of link only answers maybe require a full discussion on its own. I always felt that this cannot be yet the optimal solution. Expansion should always give prevalence over deletion and should be encouraged more.

Comment: @connor: There's a problem with adding the external content: You don't actually have the right to do so, unless OP explicitly permitted it. And he didn't.