# Marking disputed review audits as duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, meta, canonical

Over the weekend, one user appears to have cast close votes on all of the open questions under the [disputed-review-audits](/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits) tag as duplicates.

I could see this action as being constructive if we are trying to get rid of disputed review audits from meta. On the other hand, I could see blanket actions such as flagging or voting to close all questions under one tag as destructive.

What are our policies regarding this action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can not comment on general policy, except that I personally would be against indiscriminate closing of questions in this tag.

That said, I can share reasoning that led me to cast duplicate votes on *some* of these questions.

As far as I can tell, recently we've got a [canonical post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276010/839601) on how to review in First Posts and Late Answers queues:

- [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts)

Based on that, I went over some prior questions and picked those where it looked like audit failure could be avoided if reviewer was familiar with guidance given in canonical question referred above. My initial plan was to close these as duplicates of that canonical question but after closer inspection I had to change it a bit.

Thing is, many of the questions I checked appeared to be focusing on a particular, specific issue which looked like better addressed in an answer to [another, more specialized question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288698/839601), so I picked what looked like a more appropriate duplicate target for these.

---

As for mentioned "more specialized" question that served as a target for closer-matched duplicates, I also voted to close it as a duplicate of general canonical post, since it is covered in there (although as one of *many* different cases and with less attention to details).

Doing this I mostly followed an example of "canonical hierarchy" at MSE where most general guidance on particular topic is "surrounded" by duplicates that serve as convenient dupe-targets for some specific, frequently asked about sub-cases:

- [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/165773)

  - [What can I do if I'm the victim of serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28756/165773)
  - [How to act when you're being serial upvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124842/165773)

Comment: I wasn't sure if I'd hear from you here. Thanks for taking the time to explain your reasoning.

Comment: @Brian FWIW some of the questions I checked and decided _not_ to vote close, looked like waiting for _their own_ canonical guidance yet to be written. Which is not surprising, because it typically takes much time, effort (and some luck:) to build a canonical post. One can't just pull it out of thin air

Comment: @canon yes and no. Yes, in the sense that _technically_, system supports canonical posts by a feature called ["instant self-answer"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/instant-self-answer/info). No, in the sense that _content wise_, it looks difficult to get it right and attempts often fail ([example discussed here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251874/839601)). In practice, it's a mix, some canonical posts are built as instant self answers, while other grow up from regular ones

Answer (score 5):

Consider the two situations that assume that someone searched before hand:

1. You search and find a question (or two, or three) that is complaining about a review audit. Each of these questions is still open.
2. You search and find a question (or two, or three) that is complaining about a review audit. It is closed as a duplicate of another post about that particular queue. That is closed as a duplicate of the 'how should you review that queue' post.

In which situation does the person who searched first get more information about what the answers will be *before* the question is asked? If you selected #2, you are probably right.  As much as we love giving the same answer again and again (you clicked no action needed on a question that wasn't even close to being grammatically correct), the goal is to give the next person who searches first the answer. Duplicates serve this purpose.

That's all assuming that the person searches first... This is Stack Overflow (and we know how often people search first on the main site, why expect meta to be different?)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the purpose of the disputed-review-audits tag. The description says "*For questions related to specific review audits*". If that description is correct, there is no way it could be a duplicate UNLESS you are posting twice about the same review audit. If the policy is that you should just look for general information about a similar review audit failure, then the description (and other places on the site) should be changed. There are many places on the site that encourage users to post here if they disagree. It is strongly implied that moderators will review your specific case if you post here (as an appeals process of sorts) rather than getting marked as a duplicate.

EDIT: I would also note that there seems to be some inconsistencies on some of how these are handled. Without naming names, some are marking things as duplicates, while others appear to be lenient and reverse these decisions.

Comment: consider taking a look at this discussion over at MSE: [Does the new guidance on duplicate questions suggest closing a question as duplicate, if the original answers the OP's question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217406/165773)