# Why do we close review audit disputes as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, meta

The question [I do not understand why I failed this audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303795/6388243) has [quite a few "duplicates"](/questions/linked/303795). I sampled a few of them (aka the first few because I am a lazybones), and… I don't think they're duplicates. Allow me to explain why.

Much of these questions, in my eyes, are not *"Why was a terrible post chosen as a positive audit?"* or *"Why was a quality post chosen for a negative audit?"* but rather *"Was I correct in going against **this particular audit**, and if not, why was <x> the correct action?"* That's a bit specific for broadly closing them as duplicates of the same question<sup>1</sup>.

Not to mention that [I do not understand why I failed this audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303795/6388243) should not be the canonical anymore. As of a full *year* ago, [the FAQ post on audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/335772) has a section on bad audits and why they exist.

Which brings me to my next point…

> ♦ moderators can <s>remove the audit from your history so it doesn't count towards a potential ban</s> occasionally lift or shorten a ban, and other users can cast votes to counteract the automatic decisions that led to it being chosen as the wrong type of audit. If you get banned as a result of failing a bad audit, the ban can be lifted as well.

In other words, these questions are also supposed to draw attention to the posts as well as the fact that there was a bad audit.

So why do we close these as duplicates? Can we reopen some of these?

---

<sup>1</sup> As per [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289436/6388243), if the answer is "no", and it's a First Posts or Late Answers audit, then [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505/6388243) is an appropriate dupe target.

Comment: Unless something has changed I'm not aware of - someone needs to remove: *♦ moderators can remove the audit from your history so it doesn't count towards a potential ban* as that's not the case...

Comment: Can you please clarify what benefit you expect from re-opening questions you've suggested? I bet most (if not all) linked duplicates already have they corresponding SO audit question acted on so it is no longer audit and hence don't bring any useful information by themselves...

Comment: @JonClements any reason why you could not make change yourself? Would be more credible  as regular users have no inside whether particular moderator feature is real or not...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov because I don't *need* to, it's a community wiki on MSE so makes no odds who edits it, I don't have time to do so and just thought I'd pop a note out there before I forget that it'll need editing at some point...

Comment: Stephen, I see that [it was you who added the quoted section to the MSE FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/157172/16). Can you elaborate on where you heard that information and why you thought it was correct?

Comment: @CodyGray I really can't say. I made that edit a year ago.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Jon Clements already said, the claim that diamond moderators have any power over audits is mistaken. As far as I know, we don't. We have no magic button to remove a post as an audit candidate, and we certainly don't have the power to remove a *previous* audit from a reviewer's history. So, while cathartic, bringing it to our attention is not all that useful.

The only thing a moderator can do to help you out is lift a review ban that you might have landed yourself in after failing an audit. The problem with this is, bans aren't handed out for failing a single audit, so in order to earn yourself a ban, you have to have made a *number* of bad reviews. Generally speaking, even when someone fails a bad audit, when we look their their history, we find that the ban is not completely unwarranted. There could conceivably be cases where we decide to shorten a ban, but frankly, we don't need the question to be open in order to do this. The Meta questions aren't even all that helpful, because no one ever gives a full description of *all* the recent audits they've failed...

The only real benefit in having a Meta question open (as opposed to closed as a duplicate of a canonical) is to allow discussion about *the particular audit*. I'll grant that this is sometimes useful; for example, when the audit is an interesting case and actually exposes a common misunderstanding about what you should be looking for in the review queues. But the more common case is far less interesting. It's just a post that got inexplicably upvoted and thus nominated by the system as an audit when it is really *not* a good example of something that fits our guidelines.

In these common cases, I believe it makes more sense to close the questions as duplicates of a canonical that explains:

- Audits are necessary to stop abuse in the review queues, and are, on the whole, quite effective at doing so.
- They are automatically chosen based on a set of heuristics, which are imperfect and occasionally subject to error. Sometimes, you get unlucky.
- Even then…errors don't happen all that often—keep in mind the inherent reporting bias: no one ever complains when they *pass* an audit.
- If you *do* come across a bad audit (whether or not you actually fail it), then you should swear under your breath, open the post in a new tab, and act on it as you normally would (*i.e.*, downvote it, vote/flag to close it, etc.). This not only addresses the larger problem (bad content on our website), but also serves to disqualify the post as an audit for the benefit of future reviewers. (Questions with pending close votes are not chosen as audits, for example, and downvotes *quickly* disqualify posts as audits.)

There's no merit in repeating that advice each time on a new question, and doing so just risks important bits being left out. One of the most important things that gets left out is that last bullet point. People get so far as the "swear under your breath", but don't always follow through with the downvoting and close-voting. The majority of "bad audit" Meta questions I see don't have a downvote on the post in question when I click through to it. (At least, not until the Meta effect sets in, and that honestly is more harmful than it is helpful in the majority of cases. You don't need a militia to do what a single soldier can do.)

So, in summary: **leave open the Meta questions about audits that are actually correct and need some explanation, leave open the Meta questions about audits that are controversial, but close the Meta questions as dupes when they're about audits that are obviously invalid**.

Comment: Still, I feel like we need a better canonical than the one we're using.

Comment: @Stephen That's a fair point. If you don't like any of the questions that currently exist, I would be happy to write a new proposed FAQ to use as a canonical. But, [the canonical you point to in the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work/157172#157172) cannot be used because it is on Meta Stack Exchange, not here. We can't close duplicates across sites.