# How can I deal with downvotes on self-answered questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, self-answer

I've been posting a significant number of Q&A questions on the main SO site in the previous 6-12 months. For me this format is not only attractive because it allows me to share my knowledge, but also an opportunity to see alternative and possibly better questions.

Since the very first Q&A question I posted, there has been the problem of downvotes to the question. I think that obviously the Q&A question (itself) should be short as "my research" is included in the answer.

I then started to add notes like

> *Note*: This is a Q&A question and therefore intentionally does not show any research effort.

This reduced the amount of downvotes significantly, but especially in the last week I always got 1+ downvote regardless.

In [my newest Q&A question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32509747/stm32-read-out-protection-via-openocd), I have written a somewhat long and extensive answer to an IMO short and precise question. @halfer suggested that I not add this remark to the question and edited it out. From my viewpoint, I'd love it if I'd not have to add a remark to any single Q&A question.

I then immediately got one downvote and two close requests because allegedly I'm looking for a book, a library of an off site resource (What?? I'm not *that* old, my eyes can't be *that* bad!? I *do not* look for any of that and IMO this is *quite* obvious given the question and answer).

Therefore my questions to you (more experienced SO fellows) are:

- How can I deal with such downvotes?
- What is the appropriate procedure to follow if the question gets closed due to (allegedly) close votes? In my case, there are two off-topic external resource close votes and one "too broad" one. I can't see why any single one of that would be true. This is quite a specific question!
- Do you believe there is something structurally wrong with my Q&A question or do you have any suggestion how to improve my Q&As?

Maybe it would be appropriate to show the close-queue reviewer that this is a Q&A question (I'm not sure if this is already implemented).

Comment: My immediate response is that a good canonical Q&A will, in the long term, attract more upvotes than the one or two downvotes you might get immediately. I too am surprised at them, given they came after you'd posted your substantial answer, and it was very clear you were posting a helpful Q&A pair. However, we have long said on Meta that people may vote as they wish, and there is no requirement for people to explain their votes if they do not choose to.

Comment: "How can I deal with such downvotes?" You don't. When it comes to Q&As, someone will always be that guy. Life is unfair.

Comment: Self-Answering a question does not exempt it from the normal quality standards we hold questions to. The existence of answers should not matter to whether a question is closed, whether by the person who posted the question or anyone else.

Comment: The second question makes no sense. You can't close a question due to downvotes, unless the downvotes were cast for the same reason given by the close reason, in which case the downvotes aren't really "wrong".

Comment: I'm reading your latest Q&A and yeah... the question is not exactly up to quality standard. As TZHX points out, your question quality should be the same no matter who answers. In general, I try not to look at who posts what on the main site, so looking into your question, I would see it as a VERY thorough answer to a poorly-researched question

Comment: *"intentionally does not show any research effort."* - I don't understand why this worked.

Comment: @BSMP Don't know for sure either, but you've taken this out of context. The research effort is contained in the answer, which is IMO obvious. The reason for the missing downvotes is IMO that (some) people in the close review queue only really look at the questions superficially and don't see it's a Q&A question.

Comment: @UliKöhler Which is *exactly what they're supposed to be doing*.  When voting on the question you vote on the quality of the question, not the quality of the answers posted to it.  It would be *wrong* of them to do anything else.

Comment: @Uli but we should never look at the poster, but at the post. And as such, your post, in itself, is not up to par. The fact that the answer contains this is NOT enough to justify such a question being sent up.

Comment: *you've taken this out of context* - I think I was unclear. What I meant was, I don't understand why including a note that your question *"intentionally does not show any research effort."* would lead to fewer down votes when the down arrow on questions states, *"This question does not show research effort..."*. I would have guessed that including that note would have led to **more** down votes, not fewer.

Comment: @BoltClock Good point. I guess that's the only direct answer you can get to this ;-)

Comment: @Patrice Not sure if I understand what you meant, but I'm not seeing the connection between an *ad personam upvote* (?) and this. What is your specific suggestion? I'd like posting an answer without any question, but SO doesn't allow. Additionally, this would mean that other people could not answer with a better solution (which is, what). I can not see *any* specific reason why. IMO the question is quite clear, and if there are better answers, I can see not reason why this question would rule out *any* of them. Yes, the topic is quite niche, but that does not matter.

Comment: @BSMP Yeah, but that's what I mean with out-of-context (might not be terminologically correct -- sorry, non-native speaker...). It wrote "... does not show research effort **because** ... Q&A ...". I think this is the important part. Just like "This question is not a duplicate **because** stuff". But I guess it you are right that this *might* attract more downvotes. We might need a psychologist to determine the reasons ;-)

Comment: But for any other iteration of "I know this question is poor quality" the 'because' part never seems to matter. For example, "I'm a new coder", "I'm new to X language", "I'm in a hurry", "I don't know what terms to use to Google this", etc. all attract a pile of down votes.  In any case, including your research effort (before you found the answer) in your question, instead of leaving it out, would help you avoid down votes.

Comment: @Patrice OK, probably I agree, but now I have a (hopefully) *clear, precise* question. But not only that, I also have a *clear, precise* answer (but there might be better ones). So far I can see not a single way how to improve this specific question to solve the alledges quality issue. How can I be up to par with a long, complex answer? I think artificially making a page-long question just so it is similarly complex is inherently bad and does not help anyone (besides my reputation, which I don't care about that much).

Comment: @BSMP OK, I unstand what you mean now, and I agree. Actually this was halfers point in the original Q&A thread. It's just that, well, empirically speaking, it was helping to avoid downvotes. Maybe statistical noise. I will certainly try that. Thanks for the specific suggestion.

Comment: @BoltClock Sorry, I totally miswrote the second question. I way referring to the close votes. Fixed now in the question. Now there are three close votes, one "too broad"  and two "off topic external resource". I can't see even the slightest reasons why one of these reasons would apply. I am *not asking* for a library etc, but for an OpenOCD solution (i.e. a set of commands). This question is also quite specific and I think making it even more specific would only do harm. I 100% agree that downvotes do no harm. But close votes might do because the question might be closed and possible deleted.

Comment: @UliKöhler "alleged quality issue"? there is no alleged one... as BSMP pointed out, not being of an okay quality and saying why you're not of an okay quality is NOT acceptable. You admit YOURSELF that you don't put in research in your question. Not a frequent user of the openocd tag, but in general, such a question in tags I visit would be closed as too broad, because that's how it reads currently... "how to do this" "how secure is this" and "write this for the whole STM32 family".... yeah, sounds like "too broad", "too broad" and "too broad", coupled with "you didn't really research"...

Comment: @Patrice I could not disagree more. What do you expect? Do you actuall expect to write "How do I integrate RDP locking into my setup [1k lines OpenOCD config] with the exact ". Is than non-broad enough for you or do I also need to specify which keyboard layout I use?. Honestly: I post solutions to *help people*. And doing it like you suggest would not all help people. Just like BSMP (as I understood him in his first post): You are taking the quote out of context. Want to see research? look at my answer. If that's not good enough, write a better answer. [Part 2 follows]

Comment: @Patrice Part 2: As I already told someone else, I *do not admit in any way or form that I did not put research into it*. This is a blatant mis-quote. What I said is "This question intentionally does not show any research effort". Some versions of this note I added also contained the note "If you want to see the research effort, look at my answer". I challenge you to write about the same topic and do it better. Possibly I can learn from that. Until then, please refrain from mis-quoting me.

Comment: @Patrice Correct me if I'm wrong but from what you wrote I don't think you have the knowledge in this topic to decide that `STM32 family` is too broad. Indeed, if you read about it, you'll see *quite clearly* that the *RDP* protection is *the same in every current STM32 product* and only OpenOCD requires you to use `stm32f1x` or `stm32f2x` for a bunch of different families. That being said, I would be OK with removing this sentence, if anyone can conclusively tell me what the added value for a user or a potential answerer would be.

Comment: @UliKöhler dude, you ask for people who, you just said yourself, don't get the technical side of your question, to help you with... the technical side of your question. We cannot help you do this. We can help you by repeating (AGAIN) that saying "but the research is in my answer" is POINTLESS and not the way it works. You don't wanna see that point? Fine, there's no reason to keep arguing this. But as long as you keep posting poor-quality questions, they will get downvoted, whether you answer yourself or not.

Comment: @Patrice OK. I guess you are right to some extent. But I don't think this is the issue here. You say that the question is too broad without knowing the technical details. Why? And you are (I think) expecting from me to do what seems impossible to me: To word a question to a (alledgedly) good answer so that you, who likely will never have the issue to think it is not too broad, well research etc. What else can I do beyond saying that I have not seen and do not see any issue with the question, considering that 2 weeks ago I had the question but not answer. [Part 2 follows]

Comment: @Patrice That being said, I am sorry to say that I have probably fallen into a huge trap and I was wrong about one quite important thing: Downvotes are not inherently a bad thing. While I think one should only vote (I don't vote on AppleScript stuff for example) on topics you have enough knowledge of, for me it pretty much does not matter if I have -1 or +125 votes on a question. What is very important to me, however, is that at any time someone without proper technical knowledge will come around and close & delete the question. It has happened before (not to me, yet).

Comment: So, maybe the differnence between many of you and me is that I (pretend to) understand something of the area the question is about, and many of you don't? I'm not sure if this is generalizable, but I think at least in this case this leads me to the conclusion that you can't really say too much about the question itself but only give generic advice that does not help me.

Comment: @UliKöhler - more generic advice: how to show research - presumable you ask question because first 2 search results on google/bing  for terms you are looking for and 2 most likely links to product documentations did not produce result. I don't see adding couple links+ one-line explanation why it did not work to question as huge burden and it will clearly show your research. If such links (or search for title of the post) immediately give the answer - maybe it is really bad question...

Answer (score 13):

All questions are to be judged by the same [high] standards.  You're asking bad questions and you're somehow surprised when you get downvotes.  Getting downvotes when you ask a low quality question is *exactly what should be happening*.   If you don't want to get downvotes then *ask quality questions* instead.

The fact that you're providing an answer to the question changes nothing about how the question should be evaluated.  Readers are expected to evaluate the question as if you're not the one answering it.  You should be making your questions good enough that people should still think that they're good questions *even looking at them in this light*.

You should not be editing meta information, such as explanations of why you're asking a bad question, into the question.  The question is where you ask your question, not where you explain why you're asking your question.

Comment: Maybe you can explain by example what I could do better? Without that unfortunately your answer is of little value to me. The only reason that *I* can see why this question could be considered not good is that I intentionally did not include "research effort". That is IMO obvious, however, considering that the "research effort" is contained in the answer itself.

Comment: @Uli: is there any way, in general, you can transfer the research from the answer to the question? This would give other people the opportunity to respond to it with their own answer in parallel with yours.

Comment: @UliKöhler Every time you're posting a question ask yourself, "What would I do if I saw someone else posting this question?"  If you wouldn't think that it's a great question, then you shouldn't be posting it.  This is of course hard; it's why I generally discourage people from trying to post self-answered questions.  Writing a good question that you already know the answer to is difficult.

Comment: @halfer Yes, actually I believe there is any some of my earlier Q&As (in more active tags) have attracted other people's answers that were simply better than mine (therefore I accepted them and changed my software's code base to adapt them). Specifically speaking, yes, I believe that in fact the OpenOCD question *can* be answered with a better solution (is there a OCD command that does this all in one command? IDK.). I can assure you that my questions are in no way tailored to the answer, quite the opposite. These are answer to questions I could not find an answer for.

Comment: @Servy True, but it does not answer my question: How can I modify the question so it is better or more adherent to the. I can assure you that, if I would find such a question, I'd do my absolute best to answer it (and I have done so numerous times). In fact, I had this (exact!) question, but I did not find any simple explanation either on SO or elsewhere. Therefore, I created both by myself.

Comment: @UliKöhler Ask yourself what you'd expect of someone asking such a question, were you to see someone else post it.  What information would you expect them to include, what information would you expect them to be able to find in their own research, how would you expect them to describe the problem, the expected behavior, etc, would you feel that the question is appropriately scoped, and not too broad or too specific.  All of that should be in the question, even when you're asking it yourself.

Comment: @Servy I have done that, not only *since this technical question emerged from my need to solve it* but also as I *tried to write the question so that is general enough for alternate answers*. You are only speaking generally and I don't think this helps. Maybe you could address this *to the aforementioned example Q&A question specifically* -- maybe I can learn a better way of asking Q&A questions from you, who knows? I see no way of doing this when you are only speaking generally with no specifics ,unless I missed them

Comment: @UliKöhler Well you've said that you're asking lots of self-answered questions.  If I just give you specifics for one then that wouldn't help you with the others.  I'm also not intimately familiar with all of the concepts that you're posting about.  I'm trying to help you learn how to ask a good question, I'm not just going to fix your question(s) for you.  You wanted to know how to ask a better question, I've given you lots of tips on the subject, and there's *tons* more out there in the help center, elsewhere on meta, and around the rest of the web.

Comment: @Servy I hope you don't mind me asking but what specific tips have you given? The one thing I can see is the *what might other people think of your questions* thing - but IMO I have already done that. I understand you have other things to do, but what exactly do you expect from me. Right now I don't have a method of improving my questions, besides BoltClock's and halfer's who are IMO the only specific methods shown here. If there are tons of (I have yet to read the alledged & probably duplicate answer above) answers, would you mind pointing me at a few that show specifics?

Comment: @UliKöhler You can [read them again](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305794/how-to-deal-with-downvotes-on-self-answered-questions/305797?noredirect=1#comment245664_305797) if you missed it the first time.  You can read the how to ask page in the help center, look through the FAQ on asking questions, etc. if you're looking for additional information on how to ask a good question.  It is of course a very broad topic, and as such can't be given a comprehensive answer in just a comment.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for the tip and for your patience. I'm not sure if I stated that clearly, but I have stated multiple times (maybe in comments to other users, not sure off my head) that when applying your methods to my question I can't devise any improvement whatsoever. For example, I'd ask a paid consultant that exact same question in the same way : `How can I lock my STM32 with OpenOCD? I need an answer for all STM32 MCUs, not only one subtype`. I 100% agree about the broad topic thing and I will read on but so far I have yet to find any method allowing me a specific improvement.

Comment: @Servy One thing to add here after reading more meta stuff. When you close and possibly delete the question (which you say, is evaluated separately), you automatically a) prevent other users from posting a better solution and b) (in case of deletion) prevent them from reading it. That does not seem logical to me, so I think questions being evaluated with no relation to an answer makes limited sense.

Comment: @UliKöhler I've not even *mentioned* deleting the questions.  Apparently the subject matter experts that had been coming across the question felt it merited closure, but even that is simply a signal to you to *fix the question* so that it can be reopened; something that you seem opposed to actually doing.  If one of your self answered question is closed, then odds are that the underlying problem that caused the closure would prevent other answers of value anyway (i.e. if the question is unclear, or too broad, it couldn't really be answered anyway).

Comment: @Servy Right, you did not and if I somehow misrepresented that, I'm sorry. I don't completely agree on your question-answer relation, however: From what I see on this thread, it seems like the answer could be a 1000-upvote one while the question does not conform to some quality standard which is (apparently) judged by people without the proper technical knowledge in the very niche area. I tend to believe if an expert would spot a huge problem (e.g. my question is utterly wrong and does not make any sense), he'd comment and I'd fix that. Until then I do not know what to fix, honestly.

Comment: @UliKöhler Yes, it's possible to have a good answer to a bad question.  If someone comes across a good answer to a bad question they'll hopefully upvote the answer and downvote the question.  You also claim that you posts are being judged by people without sufficient technical knowledge, and yet in reality  your posts were getting downvotes by people who naturally came across the questions because they're experts in the subject area, and so you came here and asked people without technical knowledge to evaluate your questions because you didn't like that the experts were downvoting you.

Comment: @Servy Yes, I basically agree on all of you points. My experience is that such questions tend to end up on some review queue where the fraction of people with specific expertise in an area is rather low. It was a mistake focusing on the downvotes and I think you are right in saying it is OK and does not matter. What I don't want to happen is that in the future someone closes & deletes the question and the answer, making it unavailable for the general public.

Comment: @UliKöhler Then if a question is closed you need to address whatever problem has cause it to get closed.

Comment: @Servy I would not care about the question being closed if the answer would remain available (only in case of deletion of course)... I have read several time on the internet that people had issues with someone deleting questions and answers years later. I do not want that to happen, regardless of the perceived quality of my question by experts and non-experts.

Comment: @UliKöhler Then the solution to that is to fix whatever problem have caused your question to be closed, rather than just ignoring them, like I *just* told you.

Comment: @Servy Sure, I have read that, but when someone tells me that the close-reason is that *i am looking for an external off-site resource* and that is the reason for the close, there is absolutely nothing I can fix. Because that is plain wrong and would he understand the technical details behind the niche area I'm talking about, he would immediately see that. You are simply giving general advice that can not be implemented, especially not in the general case. You could say that in this case I'd probably ask on Meta, and probably that's the only answer I'll get.

Comment: @UliKöhler So you're expecting me to tell you exactly what you need to change in a hypothetical question that I have no information about that might be closed for an unknown reason.  Sorry, but I can't fix such a question for you.

Answer (score -15):

One strategy you could use is to add the following text as a comment under your question, while you are writing the Q&A pair:

> *Note*: This is a Q&A question and therefore intentionally does not show any research effort. I will write a canonical answer in due course, which I believe will be helpful to readers generally. Once all of the editing is complete, I will remove this message.

This might help discourage some close/downvotes - though who can say? You *could* add this as a prominent footer into your question, with the intention of later removing it, as long as you actually do remove it. I have lost count of the times posters promise some update in the body of the question, and then forget to do so!

Edited to add an aside: I think the emerging view that the questions should be good enough to stand alone is worth hearing; I had not thought of this myself. Nevertheless, let us remember that the OP is writing helpful Q&A material, and if the *Meta* response is a terse "your questions are rubbish", he or she may just stop writing them. I don't know the subject area of the question at hand, but it looks useful to me.

Comment: There's no need to include a "I'm writing an answer" message, since when submitting Q&A style, you write your answer at the same time as the question.

Comment: @Trobbins: I had forgotten about that. Nevertheless, I would not be opposed to a question answer removing it in a couple of days, if he or she feels this helps. (I am not sure it does, but it would be hard to prove either way).

Comment: @Trobbins Generally true, but AFAIK you don't see that in the review queues. When I added this remark, the downvote rate was significantly lower (might be statistically insignificant but these are my empirical results)

Comment: @Uli your question should stand on its own merits, not that it's only posted so you may post your answer.

Comment: @Trobbins Why exactly doesn't it? I can assure you that I had this exact question months before I had found a partial answer. Yet I could not find it anywhere on the internet. When I had finally figured out the answer, I posted both on SO. It has happened before that some expert emerges from the dark and provides a better answer, making all our lives easier ;-)

Comment: @UliKöhler Well, considering that you're saying that you're editing comments into your question to say that it's bad, but it's okay because you posted an answer, makes it pretty clear that you realize full well that it's not a good question, and that it doesn't stand on your own, so you don't need us to explain to you why your questions don't stand on their own.

Comment: @halfer Very good point in your latest edit. I'd actually like to confirm that this is (at least partially) the case. On my blog I post stuff which I consider to be too long for SO (more articles and explanations that simple Q&A stuff). Voluntarily or involuntarily, if "the community" (whatever you might define that to be) does not accept my answers because they don't like the questions, I'll post both on my blog.

Comment: @Servy Where have I said that I edited comments in my post? I have tried once or twice adding this as a comment. Effect: None, as if I added  nothing whatsoever. For me adding this remark to the question is *only* a method of preventing some IMO unjustified downvotes from happenin. And you are totally and utterly wrong: I *do not* realize that this is a bad question (as I have commented several times in this thread), but I challenge everyone to come up not only with conclusive evidence that it is bad, but especially *a way to improve this question*.

Comment: @Uli: perhaps "bad" is the wrong word. What Servy is saying is that the existence of the message you add as an addendum illustrates that you understand the question lacks research (and as you say here, the research is in the answer). My view is that, possibly, the research in the answer can be moved to the question, which would then make it "researched"?

Comment: @UliKöhler Right in this meta question: `I then started to add notes like, 
*Note*: This is a Q&A question and therefore intentionally does not show any research effort."` You're explaining why it's okay for you to ask a bad question.  You then somehow think that people should therefore not downvote the question despite it being a question that merits downvotes, *by your own admission*.  I've given you *lots* of advice on how to improve your question.  You have not responded to any of it other than to ask for even more information.

Comment: @Servy OK, didn't really see that as a comment, but I guess you could define it as that. I do appreciate your efforts, but it does not help me much, because I have yet to see a method that I can apply to the aforementioned example to make better. Example: `Remove that 'please give an answer valid for that entire STM32 family' sentence. too specific`. There is a technical reason why this sentence is there, but maybe it is bad after all?

Comment: @halfer Interesting point. I do not agree, however, because a 5-screen-page question would a) not help other users find a solution at all and b) would not really allow "adding alternative/improved answers" because they would not "oppose" or "compete to" the answer but to the question itself. I don't think this matches the Q&A scheme, if the only purpose is to artificially improve the answer. The *main* if not *only* purpose of me posting stuff to SO (or to my blog) is to help other people shortcut to the solution instead. IMO you're right about 'bad

Comment: @halfer Although this answer got many downvotes and the other got many upvotes, due to the lack of specific suggestion what can be *objectively* improved in my answer I do not see any other way than either doing it with the note or just leaving it off (which would certainly be preferable) and ignoring the downvotes. Besides that, I can only wait until someone feels free to finally not give generic yet unfortunately useless advice and actually tells me what *specifically* would make them accept the Q&A, ignoring the fact that their expertise is in another area...

Comment: @Uli: I don't mind the downvotes - here on _Meta_ it just means that people disagreed with me, which is fine. I think you should consider the advice given as much as you can - it seems to be the overwhelming view here that questions should show research and effort. As you say, the reason why you are not getting specific advice relating to this question is probably because people here do not have the hardware/chip experience that you do.

Comment: If you want to improve your question on the main site, try asking yourself "What problem did I originally want to solve?", then re-writing the question together with the research you had at that point, and then finally adjust the answer so that any material that has flowed into the question is taken out.

Comment: @halfer I agree that this is the problem. But I do not really understand why people try to jude question they don't understand, then. Thanks for the tip, however, it does not really help. I have asked this question before, while and after posting the question: The problem i wanted to solve is 100% what I wrote, and this problem is real. Therefore I do not see what can be improved. Sorry if this question is too technical for some people, but this is what you encounter in embedde systems....

Comment: @UliKöhler you realize that I don't, and no one needs expertise in ANY area to realize your question does not SHOW RESEARCH. The "too broad" point that was brought up might not be valid considering the tech involved, but the research point, you cannot defend with "well you guys don't know openOCD", since there is no research in the question (by your own admission). Just adding THAT would make a lot of the complaints about your question here moot

Comment: @Patrice OK, I got that. *How* can I do that *specifically*? Am I supposed to copy the whole answer (*if* you would call that research) to the question? Really? Do I have to *artifically* create some hypothetical case where a hypothetical user has a hypothetical problem instead of a real user having a real problem? I think for someone finding the post on Google, this question, as-is is most useful and any change would be detrimental to the usefulness.

Comment: @UliKöhler Then if you have NO INTENTION whatsoever to do ANY CHANGE to your question until someone edits it for you (because with all the tips that people CAN give you, you always push back), just don't edit it. In general, put SOME RESEARCH. Weirdly, Alexei Lenkenov gave you SPECIFIC tips... and you just ignore his comments. People giving you what you want, you ignore, and you fight back everyone else. Keep posting your Q&As, some will be closed, most will be DVed... but at this point, you know how to make it not so.

Comment: @Patrice a) Wrong. Would I have no intention I would not have started this thread. b) Wrong. I had a conversation on another of my Q&A with him leading to me marking one of my own Q&As as a dupliate. c) Wrong. So far I have only received general advice that can not be implemented or I'm too dumb to realize how to do so (and yet no-one has given me a *specific* hint). I do not care about downvotes and if you don't care about *actual solutions for real problems* on SO, then I don't know what to say.

Comment: @UliKöhler so you realize on one hand you keep saying people knowing nothing about your issue are the ones closing, turning to the SAME PEOPLE for the specific technical thing you need. Dude, the ACTUAL solution is TO PUT SOME RESEARCH IN. It may make the question long, but so be it. that's what everyone's been saying. THAT's your specific help here : PUT SOME RESEARCH IN YOUR QUESTION. If you don't care for downvotes, don't put some research in, what do you want us to say? We give general because we can't give better, and you keep on pushing back. In a tag with 60 questions, you may be one

Comment: @UliKöhler of the only experts about OpenOCD on this site, so we can't provide more. People are helping you to the best of their knowledge, and you just fight back, send snarky comments, answer "wrong wrong wrong" to everyone, and back up in a corner. Look, edit or don't, I don't care anymore. I've said what I had to say, Servy gave you similar tips, halfer gave you other tips, Alexei gave you other tips. Listen, or don't, I'm done repeating. It would indeed be a shame if your questions get closed because they look useful, but if you don't want to take any help and never edit, then too bad

Comment: @Patrice How? How can I put some research in? My research is 100% in the answer, so *how* can I do that? Shall I just copy? Maybe you could give me a link to a Q&A question which you think is perfect? I have said numerous times now that your accusations are plain wrong and I'm sorry but without even an *example* (totally independent on OpenOCD) I can not see *what* should be edited

Comment: @UliKöhler you might not understand "I'm done"... but... I'm done.

Comment: @Patrice No, you are not -- If you were, you wouldn't write one more post. But let's stop this, it is leading nowhere and I hope that if someone in the far  future might actually some implementable feedback. In the meanwhile I can do nothing but leave the note away (which I'll try). Besides that I see no, absolutely no way *how* I can implement this and I suspect most commenters here also don't see any specific way... unfortunately.