# Self answers for trivial stuff that could be easily learned from the documentation page

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I know that SO has a policy for self-answers. But what about asking a question which is really trivial and the answer is easily searchable at the documentation (by easily I mean that there is a whole section "how to do X" with detailed explanation) and then answering this question in a matter of seconds.

The reason for asking this, is because I saw this behavior and in my opinion this does not provide any good and I can create huge amount of these questions/answers in a matter of a couple of minutes just by reading documentation and rephrasing a little bit what's written there?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Can you post a link?

Comment: @Pekka웃 http://stackoverflow.com/q/33792118/1090562 (the Q/A also got an upvote in first 5 minutes, which is strange because this tag is pretty new)

Comment: @SalvadorDali Python isn't a particularly new tag...

Comment: @Servy oh sorry, haven't noticed python tag. The question has almost nothing to do with python. It is all about TensorFlow NN library

Comment: Why not lower the value of the "copied and edited" answer by posting an Answer that states the self-answer has obviously been taken from [link to the source] and that the source documentation is more complete and understandable? Might be enough up-voting on yours and down-voting on the "plagiarism" to make it not worth the person's while...

Comment: @Cindy Meister: That'd be more appropriate as a comment than an answer. As an answer, it's really no better.

Comment: @gnat I think that this is from the point of view from the downvoter/third party, while yours is from the OP point of view.

Comment: @Braiam I think [top answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251878/839601) over there is applicable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tricky one, that one. It currently has a lot of downvotes, presumably for the "this question does not show any research effort" and that's quite valid.

However, it doesn't seem to meet any of the current *standard* criteria for being closed, and it's certainly to do with a tool primarily used for development.

So, from a "legal-ish" viewpoint, I suspect downvoting is the best redress here, along with a comment which you seem to have done (the comment, I mean - I have no idea if you've downvoted).

However, keep in mind that there *is* the `other` reason for off-topic closing which basically lets you use any reason you want.

If you were to use a reason like "I don't like the color scheme of your avatar", you'd probably bring down the wrath of the swarm on yourself.

But I think you could make a case for something being off-topic if it doesn't actually add *value* to SO (such as if the subject matter is covered on page two of the documentation).

In the end, you just have to vote your conscience.

Comment: `But I think you could make a case for something being off-topic if it doesn't actually add value to SO` That's a fantastic case for downvoting, but it's not a reason to close a question.

Comment: Or you could make a case *the other way,* which @Servy has done :-)

Comment: Related: [Introduce a "general reference" close reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86043)

Answer (score -15):

I disagree that it is not good for SO.  If the objection is RTFM then it is worth noticing that for all practical purposes SO *is* the manual.

Say for example I don't use python much and I can't remember the syntax of a `for` loop.  I go to Google and enter something like "python syntax for loop" and more often than not the top result is on SO and exactly this kind of question, simple, easily found in the official documentation.  But it came up first in the Google ranking, and with a good clean answer the information is there in exactly the byte sized chunk that I was looking for.

I find it singularly frustrating to be shown my exact trivial easily answered question but find only flags about duplication, off topic, lack of research etc. instead of an actual answer.  To my mind that gives a disservice to SO.

The only other objection I can think of to the behaviour (creating a lot of simple questions and answers) is that it 'unfairly' allows someone to build a high rep.  Personally I don't see why that matters.

Comment: Have you at least read my question? My question is whether it makes sense to ask obvious questions and then answer them in a second with a stripped of version of the manual. And I justify my reason that it is bad with the fact that by spending one hour I can generate close to 10 such low quality Q/A

Comment: Yes, I read the question and my answer: yes I think it makes sense.  I don't understand why creating 10 questions with answers in an hour is bad and contend that they are not low quality simply because the information can easily be found in the manual.

Comment: They are bad because you are simply duplicating content (even not duplicating but making a worse version of it, where you just copy paste a little bit of code from here and there. Content which you are not willing to support and when the documentation will be changed or updated you most probably will not go and update all your 10 questions. You can also look at that answer and see the documentation. And then ask yourself "does it add any value"?

Comment: _"for all practical purposes SO is the manual."_ No, it is not. SO is not, and shouldn't be an API. SO is where you come to (get) help fixing a programming problem. It's dev support, not documentation.

Comment: @Cerbrus Stack Overflow isn't meant to be a substitute for official docs, but it's not a support site either. It's a Q&A site. We have multiple close reasons that are specifically targeted at closing support questions that don't have lasting value to people other than the asker.

Comment: Let's all just agree to use the phrase "programming problem" exclusively and leave it at that. No trigger words like "help" and "support", please.

Comment: Everything that @meesern says is totally correct.  Of course SO is now "the manual" in the phrase RTFM.  The "community feeling" against easy or trivial questions, is, just a silly notion from the early days of this site. Trivial questions, and correct "canonical" answers to those trivial questions, should be welcomed on the site.  Nutty "off topic" etc. flagging is just seen as nonsensical insider clutter, by normal people visiting the site.

Comment: Yes, agree with @JoeBlow.  There is an important point that gets lost in these kinds of discussions about moderating questions.  While SO is a brilliant resource that essentially makes my job possible, I never actually turn to SO for the answer to _anything_.  I turn to Google, and Google turns to SO.  If SO is a repository for correct answers to trivial (but worthwhile) questions then they are adding lasting value to the community at large. It is bad IMHO for SO to have question that search engines throw up as the top result, and then refuse to answer them for political reasons.

Comment: Not that it matters, but also the linked "duplicate" question to this meta question has no relationship at all to the issues at hand here.