# Help Me Understanding Downvote Reason for Knowledge Sharing Question

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting, self-answer

Today I have asked a question regarding the windows VPN client link and answered it to share my knowledge. I got a downvote for both the question and the answer. May I know what is wrong in knowledge sharing?

Please help me understand how can I improve them?

Comment: Just a warning: don't post minor issues that aren't even issues here on meta. Please delete it or I guarantee you'll get a ton crap of downvotes here too :)

Comment: @ʇolɐǝz ǝɥʇ qoq, I approved your edits. 1 upvote for your edited questions.

Comment: Some SE sites/users encourage self-answered questions while other sites/users discourage them.  To understand [so] policies and its community sentiment a more appropriate place to ask about a question you posted there would be [meta.so].

Comment: @manjesh23 I will edit my post to explain reputation system a bit more, since I don't think you get it.

Comment: @ʇolɐǝzǝɥʇqoq Roger that

Comment: Are you asking why you were downvoted, or are you asking how to improve your questions? The former is unanswerable, the latter is much more constructive.

Comment: Well, for one, your question is completely off-topic for SO, as it's not a programming question, it's a question about troubleshooting an application.

Comment: [Is this your question and answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625382/uninstall-broken-sonicwall-gvc/34625404) Your quesiton is totally off-topic for [SO]. It isn't about programming and you should ask (and answer) it on [su] as well.

Comment: That'd make a pretty good answer, @Kevin...

Comment: @Shog9: Oh yeah, let me post one.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272443/understanding-downvote-reason

Comment: Told you about the incoming downvotes :)

Comment: Seems like that guy who downvoted my GVC questions is giving downvotes for all my questions and answers and I am losing reputation.

Today I started with 30 rep and now I am at 18. That is something cruel right???

Comment: How can I track him or report this to stackoverflow?

Comment: No I am at 14, please help...

Comment: After deleting that questions I am back to 28, but trust me there are cruel people here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)

Comment: I don't think sticking "When is it justifiable to downvote a question?" is very helpful for beginners, especially when asking improvements from specific questions

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå no, duplicate of [Tried to add a self-answered wiki-post, but just got downvotes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251874/tried-to-add-a-self-answered-wiki-post-but-just-got-downvotes)

Answer (score 13):

So I found your question and answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625382/uninstall-broken-sonicwall-gvc/34625404 (deleted, for 10k+ users)

Your question is totally off-topic for Stack Overflow. It isn't about programming. You should ask (and answer) it on [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) as well.

From our close reasons:

> Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

---

**Ask** these questions on Stack Overflow:

- a specific programming problem, or
- a software algorithm, or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

**Ask** these questions on Super User:

- computer hardware,
- computer software, or
- personal and home computer networking

---

Relates:

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
- https://superuser.com/help/on-topic