# Is it valid to ask a question to really answer it myself for other questions closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, questions

There are just an inordinate number of questions revolving around `debugging ajax calls`.

[asp.net mvc http[post] internal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37633650/asp-net-mvc-httppost-internal-error)

[jQuery Ajax - Internal Server Error 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279425/jquery-ajax-internal-server-error-500)

etc, etc, etc..

Is it reasonable or property for me to create a wiki question which really answers the base question; *What is an Ajax Internal Server Error 500, and how do I fix it* similarly to the question [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: If it's well written, why not?

Comment: May be read [some material](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251874/tried-to-add-a-self-answered-wiki-post-but-just-got-downvotes) before doing so.