# How should questions that you plan to answer on your own be phrased?

Tags: discussion

I did not realize until recently that Stackoverflow encourages posting questions that you plan to answer on your own in order to share your knowledge. What is the best way to phrase such questions? It seems strange to post a question asking if there is any solution to an issue if you already know the answer. Is there any phrasing for questions that you post that you know you are going to answer that is recommended?

Comment: Make it look like any other question really. If you don't make it look like any other question (that has a question, and could in theory also be answered by anyone else) you run the risk of it getting closed because it doesn't conform to the Q&A format.

Comment: I'm somewhat disappointed this wasn't self-answered.

Comment: @Gnat this is not a duplicate of that question. I am asking for general guidelines, not for advice because a question that I posted was voted down.

Comment: Title of the duplicate question is slightly off but that doesn't matter. General guidelines are right there, [in the top answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251878/839601) - "Questions asked on this site are expected to be of high quality. The fact that you answered it yourself is entirely irrelevant..." etc. Second top answer over there is also worth reading - again, for general guidance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You phrase your question like a question, and your answer like an answer. All like you normally would if you weren't the author of both bits of information.

So don't ask your question with the answer already in mind. Ask the question the way you would have, before you thought of the answer to it. Include all the things we require from anyone else asking a question. Show us your code, demonstrate your problem, give us anything we need to reproduce the issue. Only once you've done that, you can think of the answer.

A great answer is no excuse for a crappy question, no matter if you're the OP of the question or not. And we won't hesitate to close or downvote your question if it's not up to scratch.