# Documenting through self-answered questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, self-answer

Back in a year or so I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060436/what-are-the-new-features-in-c17) which is an attempt to make SO a reference for documentation. This quite puzzled me as I was (and still am, at least to an extent) considering SO more like a "helpdesk" than a documentation site.

I must admit after a few times answering and correcting some questions that it gets frustrating when not being able to link quality, related content (full duplicate or part to the solution) as it may be sometimes very lacking. Which is why I now also consider a minimal FAQ to be valuable.

But sometimes, the question doesn't come, gets deleted because OP thought it was too dumb or too simple of a problem (happened today), or simply contain too much specificity or noise to represent a clean future use.

Here comes the utility of self-answered questions, as a mean for documentation and link for future use, like a FAQ. Still, I ask myself what are possible pitfalls, do and don't of self-answered questions :

- How useful would be a documentation extract, like the example linked ?
- Is there a format a question like this should take ?
- Is it OK to partially dupe a question to make a reusable example from it ? If not, what is the favored way ?

Comment: According to some Stack Overflow is meant to be a knowledge repository, though depending on who you ask it might not really be going in that direction. My opinion, it's a tossup; it's about evenly split with voting powers on both sides. Regarding selfie Q/A, IMO we should assume good faith on contributors if their post is readable and isn't a direct copy/paste of the documentation (which might cause legal problems). This isn't really supported by the site, though, selfie Q/A is hard and puts a pretty big burden on the asker.

Comment: *"an attempt to make SO a reference for documentation"* - I'm not sure what this means, to be honest. It's an objective, answerable question, and it's received an answer. You characterise it as a *"documentation extract"*, but I'm not sure what that means or how this qualifies; I'd expect a "documentation extract" to be a copied-and-pasted quote from some documentation, but that's not what this is. -1 not to express disagreement but to express that I can't really parse the question you're asking, here.

Comment: @MarkAmery "documentation extract, like the example linked" If you read the linked example, the accepted answer is list of links to the documentation.

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri Well, firstly, I'm not sure I agree with the characterisation as a "list of links"; rather, it's a list of *features*, which for convenience and corroboration are presented with inline links to the standard. If you completely stripped all the links out of that answer, the plain text of the answer would still be useful (and an answer to the question) in its own right. But secondly, even if it really were just a list of plain links, that's not what an "extract" is. An extract is a *"a short passage taken from a text"* (per Google `define:`), not a link or a collection of links.

Comment: SO don't favor broad questions, if you attempt to write something like this now it will likely be downvoted and closed. The tags serve the purpose of "connecting" multiple questions together. To example, talking about [tag:c#-7.0] there are multiple off-site resources talking about features, but I don't see question "what are ALL features of c# 7.0" on SO, I'd downvote that post myself no matter how much effort the poster did, because I find it useless, I'd never use it in my answers or votes, rather I'd write self-sufficient answer with link to blog.

Comment: @Sinatr That question is only three years old. I don't think our standards have changed much in the last three years. A question of such breadth certainly *would* be at risk of closure if asked today, but it was three years ago, too; a quick glance at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38060436/revisions) reveals that a battle was once waged here.

Comment: "SO more like a helpdesk" - This made me think about the nature of SO, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> How useful would be a documentation extract, like the example linked ?

I was recently in the situation where I was looking for this exact list of changes (to show some of the benefits of a compiler upgrade). This list is exactly what I was looking for. There are several other sites that have similar lists but I couldn't easily find any "official", easily consumable list, so this isn't merely duplicating official documentation.

> Is there a format a question like this should take ?

The question itself must still fit the site. It must be answerable and fit all the other various criteria. The linked question does that.

It might of course differ in tone from the questions you usually see, because most of those are "I have problem X, how can I fix it?". But contrary to some public perception, the stated objective of StackOverflow is to create a (or rather *the*) high quality knowledge body for programmers, not to be a programming help desk. We still tend to answer a *ton* of questions that have no chance of helping anyone but the asker.

It can be a good idea to create a "comprehensive dupe target" if you frequently see questions that boil down to the same problem. One such example would be [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix), which means people in the C++ tag don't have to constantly rattle down a checklist in the comments to figure out how the asker messed up their build. It's less immediately helpful to whoever gets his question dupe-hammered with it (they have to read and go down the list themselves), but it's immensely valuable for keeping people in the tag sane and google results pointing to a *good* answer for the problem. All the duplicates also act as "signposts". Again, all in the interest of creating a high-quality knowledgebase, not of being live programming help.

> Is it OK to partially dupe a question to make a reusable example from it ? If not, what is the favored way ?

IMO that might be a difficult choice to make. If you intend to create such a "comprehensive dupe target" then you probably want to write a new question specifically for that purpose, unless an existing question is already *very* close to that (in which case answering that and possibly editing the question to be more generally relevant might be the way to go).

Just in case you haven't read Jeff Atwood's article:

- https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

There is also some good discussion in the related questions:

- [Are self-answered questions still encouraged on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332694/are-self-answered-questions-still-encouraged-on-stack-overflow?rq=1)
- [How to ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-to-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting-d)