How can I improve my question about modeling a sum type in doctrine?
A while ago I wrote How to model a soft enum using a backing table in an attempt to figure out how I could model around an existing database layout.
I've included sample data for the tables as well as some example of what I would like to write for the entities in an attempt to make what I'm asking for clearer.
Despite this, the question has received some downvotes.
Is it just too niche of a question or is there anything I can improve about it?

I think you may be a little over-sensitive at a few DV but perhaps a SME can offer suggestions.

You earn consistently the PHP penalty and that is topped off with a self-answer penalty.  Thank you for your contribution, it is appreciated. Some of us express that with votes of the down type. Not much you can do about that. Sorry for being a confusing community.

related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332694/are-self-answered-questions-still-encouraged-on-stack-overflow  and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-do-i-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting

My 2cts, you could maybe mention (in the Qt) stg like: "Alright, I managed to find a workable solution (posted as Answer), but I would still be interested if somebody could post a "better" implementation..." (and define what "better" would mean). + In your Answer, "While not quite the solution I was looking for" sounds a bit vague to me, you could clearly explain what exactly is not optimal in your solution...

I'm not going to take a position on whether the downvotes are warranted.  But since you ask whether there is anything you can improve about it, I'll offer some suggestions.  Often even great questions can be improved further.
Let's review the mission of Stack Overflow.  It is a place where people can collaborate to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others.  We are building a library, in the form of questions and answers.  The purpose of questions is not to help a single person.  It is to identify a problem that many people have, and work together to document a solution, so many can be helped.
With that in mind, I think there are some opportunities for improvement.  The problem statement is given only by an example -- and a fairly complicated one at that.  How likely is it that others will have the same problem? And if they do, will they be able to find this page via websearch?  I doubt it.  They're unlikely to have exactly the same set of data tables you list.
I think you could work on giving a general specification of the problem.  Right now the only thing I see is "soft enum using a backing table", but that is rather vague.  You could edit the question to include a clearer problem statement.  What is the general problem?  What is the desired output?  I do not see a single question in your post.  "model the relations" also seems a big vague to me.  You could consider what keywords others with the same problem might use to search for a solution.
I also think it would be helpful to specify what are your requirements or criteria you will use for evaluating answers.  Are you OK with any code that does something that could be said to "model the relations" or computes some specific output?  Or do you require that it be implemented solely using the Doctrine ORM?  Are you OK with a solution that creates new tables or views?
