# I provided a Q&A pair with a question that was too broad. What are my options?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, needs-more-focus

At the risk of asking another question that will be poorly received:

I wanted to share some knowledge I had recently acquired, and as I couldn't find a simple answer to my original research question I decided to share it here on Stack Exchange as a question and answer pair.

However, the question I posted has been marked as too broad and put on hold, I will accept that criticism. My thought process at the time was that, because I was also providing an answer, I could get away with a broader question. To some extent I accept that was I was wrong in that assumption [as explained here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251874/tried-to-add-a-self-answered-wiki-post-but-just-got-downvotes/251878#251878). But on the other hand I feel as though my question and answer are still valid and that it will help other people that find it.

Early in my research I posted this question:

*[A better Python package manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58147272/a-better-python-package-manager/58147304#58147304)*

After getting to the end of my research I wanted to share my knowledge, and I felt that the answer I had come up with didn't perfectly fit my original question. Partly because I actually felt my original question was too broad, and therefore unsearchable.

I decided to create a new question with more specific terms in the title (i.e. specific package managers that do exist), answer it and mark my original question as a duplicate.

*[Feature comparison between npm, pip, pipenv and poetry package managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58218592/feature-comparison-between-npm-pip-pipenv-and-poetry-package-managers?noredirect=1#comment102814308_58218592)*

Do you think my question can be salvaged and made not-too-broad? Or should I have a chosen a different platform to share my knowledge? Or is my question-answer pair flawed in some other more fundamental way?

Comment: No, i don't think there's a way that question can be worded such that there aren't at least 5 people who would deem it too broad.

Comment: If not too broad it also reads as "library recommendation"... "Best {package manger} of the month" type of questions are very hard to make on topic... Maybe it will be easier to make post on-topic on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: More generally, why should any question with a good answer be closed as "too broad" — be it self-answered or not?  Part of the point of "too broad" is because it makes it hard to identify what would make an adequate answer, but if it's garnered a good, thorough answer, then why should it be closed?