# Question was deleted while I was writing an answer, but the answer is still useful

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-questions

I made a really good answer to: [How to programmatically set the sequence of equations using VBA according to variables' precedence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68383645/how-to-programmatically-set-the-sequence-of-equations-using-vba-according-to-var)

The question basically asks how to parse expressions that are in a cell to find the variable names so that the expressions can be numbered in the order they need to be evaluated - but it wouldn't be too big a stretch to also calculate the values of the expressions after knowing what order they need to be evaluated in.

I don't know why it was deleted - it happened while I was writing the answer.  It is really annoying to spend hours writing an answer and then not be able to give it to the asker.

So now I have an answer but there appears to be nothing I can do with it.  Even if I can't post it (which is a bit of a shame) at the very least it would be helpful to the person who asked the question.

Is there no way to share my answer with the asker?  Even if I could send them a link to an external page, it would be better than wasting the answer...

Comment: The person who asked the question deleted it voluntarily, so presumably they weren't that much in need of an answer.

Comment: If you believe the question was good you can ask variation of it yourself and self-answer... Also obviously author of the question re-posted the same question (in violation of the rules)... so just post your answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68387422/how-to-programmatically-set-the-sequence-of-equations-in-vba-according-to-variab)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  I didn't even think to look for another post for the same exact question.  Thanks - that really solves the question about how to share my effort.

Comment: The question you were answering, however, was very poorly received (-4 score). Often answering such questions isn't a good idea either. In truth, you are probably better off asking your own well formatted question and answering [like you’re on Jeopardy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: @Larnu while I agree with you, the Lifejacket and Lifeboat badges suggest that answering such questions is encouraged by the site.

Comment: I said *often* not always, @miken32 . *Normally* such questions also benefit from a good edit when those badges are awarded.

Comment: I modflagged the re-asked question because of the rule violation, hopefully it will be gone shortly. I despise queue-jumpers.

Comment: I wonder if there would be a way to warn a user that is attempting to delete a question that there are currently people in the process of writing an answer to it.

Comment: IMO the question should never receive an answer

Comment: Also, if you are going to answer, don't link to Google drive like you did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68387422/how-to-programmatically-set-the-sequence-of-equations-in-vba-according-to-variab#comment120995328_68387422). As enthusiasts and professionals we should all be *well* aware of how foolish it is to download a file from as complete stranger (unfortunately, too many are not). If you want to post an answer, do so as an answer.

Comment: Human race condition. Unsafe by default. Write at your own risk!

Comment: @Larnu That's why we have VMs.

Comment: Argh this happened to me some time ago too, was very frustrating >:(

Comment: No, this is why we ask users to include information important to the answer/question in the question/answer, @jeffbRTC . Users shouldn't need to have a VM available to be able to consume a question/answer safely. Links can compliment a post, such as documentation, related articles and (SQL) Fiddles, but they should rarely include downloads unless from trusted sources; such as a Microsoft KB.

Comment: @Larnu I agree with you.  I should have known better than to post a link to an excel workbook.  I just didn't want to spend the time to answer the question again because I wasted a bunch of time already but I also wanted to salvage some of my wasted time.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a perfect example of why the [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page in the help center recommends that you save yourself some frustration and only answer well-asked questions.

The question is unclear and shows no effort whatsoever by the OP. See: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) as well as [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Also, answering code-writing requests just encourages people to write more questions like that. In addition to keeping the site clean, closing questions gives OPs an incentive to improve their question in order to get it re-opened. See also: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)

As previously pointed out, you could write a question and self-answer it, but if you do please be sure that the question is well-formulated. Even if you're self-answering, the question is still expected to meet normal site quality standards, and doing so makes the answer more useful because future readers will have adequate context for it.

Comment: The thing is, I have had this exact problem before except I wanted to actually evaluate the expressions to calculate the result - the hardest part was ordering them in the right order.  I figured that if I had needed to figure it out and someone else needed to do it too then it was something I could help with.  It is a "please figure it out for me" question.  I have been there (not knowing the right questions to ask) and that's why I don't ask questions here - if I know the path to solve it I can figure it out myself.

Comment: I have seen people delete questions that were very well asked: I suspect that having found a solution (via SO or otherwise) they didn't want it to be on the public record that they had had a problem in the first place. Or perhaps they just didn't think anyone else would be interested.

Comment: the well-askedness of some questions can be in dispute.

Comment: Deleting a question has nothing to do with its quality whatsoever. I am not sure how you could assume this is related. There are literally a million possible reasons a question gets deleted, from "The asker wanted to delete it" up to some "AttentionHungry" person down flagging it for deletion.... truly this has nothing to do with the issue. Even very well formulated questions get deleted, for the _same_ million reasons as just outlined above. Not a fan of those questions "I expect you to do everything for me" neither, but this is not a perfect example as of why to answer only well asked stuff.

Comment: consider [edit]ing to add a reference meta discussion to the last paragraph about self-answer, eg [Tried to add a self-answered wiki-post, but just got downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251878/839601)

Comment: @BedaSchmid I suspect there's a strong statistical correlation between whether a question is deleted and its (admittedly subjective) quality.  Low quality questions tend to attract downvotes; downvoted questions are presumably more likely to be deleted by their asker.  And that's not counting the automatically deleted questions by the [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba), which are definitely deleted due to being likely of low quality.

Answer (score 36):

Questions such as the one you attempted to answer to are frowned upon here because they are essentially asking you to do all their work for them. Answering such questions encourages people to treat this site like a free IT support helpdesk, which is abjectly **not** its purpose. There's also the problem that many of these fly-by-night askers delete their questions after asking them, regardless of whether they get an answer or not. (In this case, it's because they're trying to evade the rules by deleting their bad question and re-asking it later so it gets more visibility than if they'd just edited it; this is an outright violation of the site rules, so don't expect the new question to be around for too long.)

Now, there's nothing stopping you from answering such questions, if you feel your time is worth that little and you're willing to run the risk of your high-quality answer being nuked with the question. A better option, as suggested in the comments, is to ask your own question on the subject and self-answer it with your solution. You're unlikely to delete your own question, after all.

However, I'd honestly question whether this is a question that needs an answer at all. It's an incredibly specific use-case which means it's unlikely to help anyone other than the person who asked it, which inherently makes it a poor fit for Stack Overflow. If you do decide to ask and self-answer a question on this topic, please consider rewording it into a form that would make it more broadly useful to a larger audience. For example, instead of just specifying the problem, outline a naïve attempt that someone new to VBA might be expected to make that won't work, and then in your answer show how to use more advanced features to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: This is the "correct" answer so I've accepted it.  But it isn't the "right" answer - and that means I must have the wrong perspective.  IThere are NO answers on stack overflow that couldn't have been self answered just by doing more research.  I guess my point is that I try to answer questions that I know how to answer but I don't have any special knowledge that isn't available elsewhere so that means, by definition, that none of the questions I can answer show enough research effort.   It's discouraging.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah That's not entirely correct. We are all different individuals with different learning abilities. A good question can show a real research effort and despite that effort the OP just couldn't understand or get it right. Here you can step-in by explaining them what they missed or showing your take on that knowledge found elsewhere. On the other hand, a question simply asking from us to do that research for them indeed tends to get frowned upon

Comment: "Abjectly"? Are you suggesting that it's bad that this is not its purpose?